# How to make images changes transition smoothly?

Tags: javascript, css, image, vue.js

Please help me with making a smooth change of picture through Js. There is an array with links to pictures, I iterate over it and every few seconds I change the picture. The picture changes very sharply, but I need this transition of the picture change to be smooth animation?

```
  setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById('image').src = '...';
  }, 5000);
```

***UPD***

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    count: 0,
    mass: ["https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300", ]
  },
  mounted() {

    for (let i = 0; i < this.mass.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('image').src = this.mass[i]
      }, 1000);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" id="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your html and required js for that?

Comment: For a smooth change in images, you can manage it with CSS animation using a transition effect

Comment: @BhavikKalariya update

Comment: @SarveshMahajan Like this ?
`document.getElementById('img').style.transition= 'transform 1s ease';`

Comment: Please take reference from this jsfiddle, you can increase or decrease time duration: https://jsfiddle.net/81o7qxrd/

Comment: @SarveshMahajan Interesting, but that’s not quite what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        count: 0,
        mass: ["https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300", ]
      },
      mounted() {

          let i=0;
          setInterval(() => {
          i = (i+1) % this.mass.length;
           fadeIn(document.getElementById('image'), 1000); 
            document.getElementById('image').src = this.mass[i];    
          }, 4000);
      },
    })
    
    
function fadeIn(el, time) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;

  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / time;
    last = +new Date();

    if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };

  tick();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
    <transition name="fade">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" id="image" />
      </transition>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is amazing! But unfortunately I do not use jquery in my project)

Comment: @IlonMask please wait